# If else on Mono if empty or has value

Tags: spring-webflux, reactive

This is the sample code

```
repo1.findById( id )
                .map( p -> {
                    if( p == null ){
                        return  repo2.findById( id ).flatMap( g -> {
                            g.setValue("some value");
                            return g;
                        });
                        
                    }
                    else{
                        return  repo3.findById( id ).flatMap( h -> {
                            h.setValue("some value");
                            return h;
                        });
                    }
                });
```

Any better way to do this ?. If else inside flat map does not look neat to me.

Comment: map wont get triggered if there is a null value, as Mono or flux are not allowed to contain null values. So the nullcheck is not needed and you should use map or switchIfEmpty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic approach would be to use the `switchIfEmpty()` operator.

You would only proceed to use the call to `repo3` if `repo1` actually returns a result.

If not data matches `repo1.findById(id)`, then this call would return an empty result, not `null`.

To cover this case, use `switchIfEmpty()`.

```java
public Mono<Data> load(String id){

        return repo1.findById(id)
                .flatMap(p -> {
                    return repo3.findById(id)
                            .flatMap(h -> {
                                h.setValue("some value");
                                return h;
                            });
                })
                .switchIfEmpty(repo2.findById(id)
                        .flatMap(g -> {
                            g.setValue("some value");
                            return g;
                        }));
    }
```